# How to assign an Omega to a variable

Tags: vba, string

I want to assign the Greek Capital Omega to a variable and use it in a logical test.  Greek Capital Omega is 937.

This works

```
    If Range("$A$49").Value = ChrW(937) Then Stop
```

However

```
    dim omega as string
        omega = ChrW(937)
    If Range("$A$49").Value = omega Then Stop
```

fails.

How should I assign the variable please?

Regards

Comment: It works for me. But only if I first use `Range("$A$49").Value = ChrW(937) `; if I use insert symbol > omega it fails on your first line `If Range("$A$49").Value = ChrW(937) Then Stop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that your code does not work because the real character in the cell is not the one you suppose to be, even if it looks like Omega...

Try this way, please:

1. Select the cell where you have (only) the omega character and run this code:

```
Debug.Print AscW(ActiveCell.value) '8486 in my case, but in yours maybe something else...
```

In my case, it returns 8486. It depends on what 'subset' has been used when inserting the character.

2. Only after that try using your way:

```
Sub findOmega()
  Dim omega As String
        omega = ChrW(8486) 'but use the ASCI code returned in the previous code line...
    If ActiveCell.value = omega Then Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: @hemis: Didn't you find some time to test the solution I suggested above? I cannot see any reason for it to not working, but I cannot be sure, too. I am just curious...

Comment: FaneDuru. Thanks.  The code did work.  My ASCII code was 937.

Comment: @hemis: I thought it should work... Glad I could help!